# Optimal Diophantine approximation of $\pi$

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-approximation

If the 'optimal' Diophantine approximation of $\pi$ is given by the maximum value of $M=-\log_q(\min_{\forall p \in \mathbb{N}} |\frac{p}{q}-\pi|)$ for $q \geq 2$, what is this value?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/210509/looking-for-an-effective-irrationality-measure-of-pi

Comment: Not the same question.  The answer here is almost surely the $3.429288+$ obtained from the approximation $22/7$, though $355/113$ is an impressive also-ran at about $3.202$ (further approximations should converge rapidly to $2$, but we have no technique for proving this).

Comment: Interesting. Are there any papers on the subject that you would recommend?

Comment: Recently, I encountered a relevant problem: whether or not there are integers $p, q$ with $q > 2$ such that $|\pi - \frac{p}{q}| < \frac{1}{q^4}$?